# Form não insere dados no banco após submetido

Tags: php, mysql

Por qual motivo o seguinte código não insere? Alguém experiente pode me dizer o código abaixo não apresenta erro contudo não insere no banco.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

addcurso:<input name="nome1" type="text">

<input name="botao1" type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />

addinstituição:<input name="nome2" type="text">

<input name="botao2" type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />

<?php

if (!empty($_POST['nome1']))

$nome = $_POST['nome1'];
 {
include "conecta_banco.inc";


$sql = "INSERT INTO cursos (cur_id, cur_name) Values ('$nome')";
$resultado = mysqli_query ($link,$sql);
echo "inserida";
mysqli_close($link);
}  


?>
```

Comment: Acredito que o problema esteja nessa linha `$sql = "INSERT INTO cursos (cur_id, cur_name) Values ('$nome')";` `cur_id` é uma FK ? Caso sim, você pode removê-lo dessa linha `(cur_id, cur_name)`, caso não você deve acrescentar algo nessa linha `Values('$var','$nome')`

Comment: cur_id está com auto_increment

Comment: Então, você pode remover dessa linha `cursos (cur_id, cur_name)` deixando apenas `cur_name`

Comment: não resolveu se você tiver mais alguma sugestão! eu ainda não consegui resolver por ser iniciante em programação

Comment: `$nome = $_POST['nome1'];` antes de `{` não está gerando um erro fatal? A estrutura da condicional é `if ( condição ) {}`. Coloque `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` no começo do arquivo e veja se ele não te dá uma mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Há um erro de sintaxe no IF. A {} está após a variável e não após o if.
Modifiquei o PHP para o inicio do código e funcionou sem problemas.

```
 <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['nome1'])){

        $nome = $_POST['nome1'];


        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "codeeducation");
        if ($link->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $link->connect_error);
            exit();
        }


        try{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO cursos (cur_name) Values ('$nome')";

            $result = $link->query($sql);

        }catch (Exception $e){
            var_dump($e);
        }


    }
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

        addcurso:<input name="nome1" type="text">

        <input name="botao1" type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />

     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: *[...]não apresenta erro*. por isso achei estranho.

Comment: eu tb, mas já vi gente achar que tela branca não é erro. Acontece. :)